# Link models through acts_as_taggable_on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a model `Product` which `has_many :taxons, through: :classifications`. How to implement `acts_as_taggable_on` to implement the tagging of products with the names of taxons instead of the the tags from the tag table? Is it possible or not?

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :name
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :translations, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank

  # Associations
  has_many :classifications, inverse_of: :product, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :taxons, through: :classifications
end

#app/models/classification.rb
class Classification < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'products_taxons'

  # Associations
  belongs_to :product, inverse_of: :classifications
  belongs_to :taxon, inverse_of: :classifications, touch: true
end

#app/models/taxon.rb
class Taxon < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :name
  globalize_accessors
  has_many :classifications, inverse_of: :taxon, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :products, through: :classifications
end
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have a similar use case

Comment: No, I don't remember exactly, but i used some other workaround